# Highlight specific text in richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox, highlighting

I have a window form that contain a `listbox` and some `richtextboxex`. `listbox` contains some values. When I select any value from `listbox`, `richtextboxex` bind with data according to selected value.

I have to highlight some text which is bind to `richtextbox` when I select a value from listbox, e.g.:

> Just a friendly reminder that you have <<OverdueInvCount>> overdue invoice(s), with an overdue balance of <<OverdueInvTotal>>. If you have any questions about the amount you owe, please give us a call and we’ll be happy to discuss it. If you’ve already sent your payment, please disregard this reminder.

All data is coming from database.

I want to highlight `<<OverdueInvCount>>` and `<<OverdueInvTotal>>` these words.

Comment: Define "listbox" - such a thing occurs in many different contexts, and your tags gives no clue. Winforms, ASP.NET or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (just tested this.. seems to work fine):

```
int openBrace = richTextBox.Text.IndexOf("<");
while (openBrace > -1) {
    int endBrace = richTextBox.Text.IndexOf(">", openBrace);
    if (endBrace > -1) {
        richTextBox.SelectionStart = openBrace;
        richTextBox.SelectionLength = endBrace - openBrace;
        richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
    }
    openBrace = richTextBox.Text.IndexOf("<", openBrace + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that without casting to new object with functionality you want is to override `ListBox` `DrawItem`

```
void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var item = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as <Your_Item>;

    e.DrawBackground();
    if (item.fIsTemplate)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text + "(Default)", new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
    }
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

and add this in your constructor (after `InitializeComponent();` call)

```
listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
listBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox1_DrawItem);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it use some system variable to avoid hard coding the font? On the other hand, the Format event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format.aspx) might be easier, since you don't have to do the drawing yourself.