# Highlighting a line in a RichTextBox1, line number = a variable

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a variable, lets say it = 5, and then I would like the line number 5 to be highlighted "blue" in my RichTextBox1.  is that possible at all?

Or should I use something like a ListBox, DataGridView etc.

[image]

Comment: Is this WPF or Windows Forms or Windows Universal?

Comment: if this is winforms yes this is possible. can you show us what you have tried..? also do a simple google search and you will find tons of answers.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765947/highlight-specific-text-in-richtextbox

Comment: yes it is Windows Forms Application,  so far i haven't try anything really.  i am new to C#

Comment: `so far i haven't try anything really. i am new to C#` is not good enough if you can find / navigate yourself to `Stackoverflow` then you should be able to execute a simple google search. This is not a Code Factory site..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will highlight the text in a given line in a `RichTextBox` if `WordWrap` is off:

```
void highLightALine(RichTextBox rtb, int line, Color hiLight)
{
    int i1 = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
    int i2 = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line + 1);
    if (i2 < 0) i2 = rtb.Text.Length;

    rtb.SelectionStart = i1;
    rtb.SelectionLength = i2 - i1;
    rtb.SelectionBackColor = hiLight;
}
```

Note that if `WordWrap` is true it will still highlight the line but only as far as it is visible. Its continuation on the next line will not be changed.

Also note that only `Text` can be highlighted. **Trailing empty space can't be highlighted** afaik. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030837/c-sharp-richtextbox-highlight-line?rq=1) is an example of trying to owner-draw an RTB subclass..

Comment: should i replace "rtb" with the name of my RichTextBox  "richTextBox1"?

Comment: i have tried this         void highLightALine(RichTextBox richTextBox1, int line, Color hiLight)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 5;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 6;
            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = hiLight;
        }

Comment: __No__. You should leave it as it is! You just __call__ it inserting your richttextbox as 1st paramter: `highLightALine(richTextBox1, 5, Color.AliceBlue);`

Comment: No, but i will give it another shot tonight.