# RichTextBox text color a specific line

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have this snippet of code:

```
if (newLocation.MonsterLivingHere != null)
{
    rtbMessages.Text += "You see a " + newLocation.MonsterLivingHere.Name + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

and I want the "*You see a (Monster Name)*" to be red.

I have several places I want a single line to be red, but I have a lot of other text in the box I dont want to be red. For example this piece of code needs to be red as well :

```
if(_player.CurrentHitPoints <= 0)
{
    //Display a dead message
    rtbMessages.Text = " " + Environment.NewLine;
    rtbMessages.Text += "The " + _currentMonster.Name + " killed you." + Environment.NewLine;
    //Moves the player to "Home"
    MoveTo(World.LocationByID(World.LOCATION_ID_HOME));
}
```

How can I make only part of the text red?

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of this question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085397/highlighting-a-line-in-a-richtextbox1-line-number-a-variable` since the question there is a different. If i am wrong please try and explain the answer a different way because i don't understand the answer given at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085397/highlighting-a-line-in-a-richtextbox1-line-number-a-variable`

Answer (score 0):

Set the selection colour and then the next insertion will be in that colour, E.g.

```
Color current = rtbMessages.SelectionColor;

rtbMessages.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
rtbMessages.AppendText("I am red" + Environment.NewLine);

rtbMessages.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
rtbMessages.AppendText("I am blue" + Environment.NewLine);

rtbMessages.SelectionColor = current;
rtbMessages.AppendText("I am whatever colour was set before red");
```

Comment: i have written this now, but neither 'SelectionColor' or 'AppendText' is a blue color, am i missing a class or a refrence?

And the text doesn't change it colors